# Is there any way to avoid using break; in while loop when the test include scanf()?

Tags: c, loops

In this `while` loop:

```
while (scanf("%lf", &first) == 1)
{
    printf("Enter your second float number (q to exit):\n");
    while (scanf("%lf", &second) == 1)
    {
        printf("The result is %f\n", (first - second) / (first * second));
        break;  
    }
    printf("Enter your first float number (q to exit):\n");
}
```

I want to read an input and give it to `second`, then I want to quit this loop to the outer `while` loop so I can input a non-numerical character (e.g.`q`) given to `first` to jump out of the outer loop.

But I met this question in the book *C Primer Plus*, and the book haven't told me how to use `break;` or `if` before the question, so I wonder if there's an alternative way to do the same thing. Thanks in advance.

The original question:

> Write a program that requests two floating-point numbers and prints
>   the value of their difference divided by their product. Have the
>   program loop through pairs of input values until the user enters
>   non-numeric input.

What I wanted to do is to jump out the loop as either `first` or `second` is given to a non-numerical character.

Comment: In the code posted, the inner `while` loop is just acting as an `if` -- just change it to `if` and get rid of the break.

Comment: The code is your answer to that question from the book?

Comment: @Dmitri However, the book haven't told me how to use `if`...even I know a little about how to use it

Comment: @glauxosdever Yes~

Comment: "the book haven't told me how to use if" - A book teaching loops before conditional statements should be thrown out of the window! However, I strongly doubt it does. It is more likely you skipped a chapter.

Comment: @Olaf Check the 8th Programming Question in Chapter 6, *C Primer Plus, the 6th edition* and you'll find I'm just follow the reading order...and the `if` statement is just in Chapter 7

Comment: @MuYuanLi: So part 1 of my comment applies! Just that: you very likely have missunderstood the task.

Comment: @Olaf Maybe I am...with a statement of `break` and the question is very easy to solve, and I'm sometimes a hair-splitter, which is not a good habit in language study

Comment: I see, I'm heading a wrong way...I can use just one `scanf()` to get 2 inputs and then give them to `first` and `second` respectively!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `while` with an unconditional `break` will always do that code once exactly, and is therefore just as good as an `if` - as already said by @Dmitri. Moreover, `break` only gets out of the innermost relevant block - so in your case, it will not break out of the outer `while` block.

However, most `break` calls (and, without doubt, those that are at the very end of a block) can be easily replaced by just using the right condition in the `while` clause.

Please pay attention that your code currently reads `double` values (due to the `%lf`) anyway. In order to allow quitting by entering a 'q' char, you must change the way you read input. For example, one way might be to read a string and, if it is not "q", translate it to double.